# Fetch cell value with increment in row number every day

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet which contain dates in one column (Say column A) and some values corresponding to each date in another column (Say column E). I want to fetch the value from the cell at the intersection of today's date (in column A) and it's corresponding value (in column E).

The value fetched should be assigned to a different cell (say R1). The value should automatically update in R1 since we need to fetch based on today's date.

Please provide me a formula for cell R1.

Example:
-----A----------B---------C--------D--------E 
 
5/8/2015-------------------------------------3
6/8/2015-------------------------------------3
7/8/2015-------------------------------------6
8/8/2015-------------------------------------10
9/8/2015-------------------------------------3
10/8/2015------------------------------------12
11/8/2015------------------------------------3

If today is 10/08/2015, then cell R1 should be filled with the value 12.
Tomorrow R1 should be filled with the value 3 automatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this formula in your cell R1:

```
=VLOOKUP(NOW(), A1:E11, 5, TRUE)
```

One thing is that if needed, you should modify range **A1:E11** as you like.

**ADDED**

If your R1 cell is in other sheet, use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(NOW(), sheetname!A5:E11, 5, TRUE)
```

Here, also has one point that you should modify `sheetname` to your data sheet name.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

How to fill the value of R1 suppose R1 is in a different sheet in the same excel file ?

Please do help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to solve this with a formula, so try this formula in cell R1

```
=INDEX(D:D;MATCH(TODAY();A:A;0))
```